# Creating objects with new in function and "this is nullptr" exception

Tags: c++, class, templates

I've been trying to make a template class (called List) which stores different type of objects. I created Base class to be like base in my program and Human class. Base can create new Human and to have access to them all, has a (private) pointer to List * first_h  (in every List  is stored Human* me, List * next and List * first_h (first_h in list)).
The problem is, when I add like more than 1 Human to my Base, I can't display them properly. I think it's because of creating new Human's in Base method (void Base::create_human(string name)) but everything I did don't work it out.
There are my classes:

```
class Human
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    Human(string name) { this->name = name; }
    void display() { cout << "My name: " << name << endl; }
};

template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    T* me;
    List <T>* next;
    List <T>* first;
public:
    void set_me(T* me) { this->me = me; }
    T* get_me() { return this->me; }
    void set_next(List* next) { this->next = next; }
    List <T>* get_next() { return this->next; }
    void set_first(List* first) { this->first = first; }
    List <T>* get_first() { return this->first; }
    void add(T*& created);
    void display();
};

class Base
{
private:
    List <Human>* first_h;
public:
    void set_first_h(List <Human>*& first) { this->first_h = first; }
    List <Human>* get_first_h() { return this->first_h; }
    void create_human(string name)
    {
        Human* created = new Human(name);
        this->first_h->add(created);
    }
};
```

and methods:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::add(T*& created)
{
    List <T>* temp = this->get_first();
    List <T>* new_list;
    if ((this->get_me()) == nullptr)
    {
        this->set_next(nullptr);
        this->set_me(created);
        this->set_first(this);
    }
    else
    {
        new_list = new List <T>;
        temp = this->get_first();

        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        new_list->set_next(nullptr);
        new_list->set_first(this->get_first());
        temp->set_next(new_list);
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::display()
{   
    List <T>* temp_list = this;
    T* temp;

    if (temp_list == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "There is nothing!" << endl;
    }
    while (temp_list != nullptr)
    {   
        temp = temp_list->get_me();
        temp->display();
        temp_list = temp_list->get_next();
    }
    std::cout << "End!" << endl;
}
```

and my main function:

```
int main()
{   
    Base Main;

    List <Human>* first_h = new List <Human>();

    Main.set_first_h(first_h);

    Main.create_human("Jane");
    Main.create_human("John");
    Main.create_human("Mary");

    Main.get_first_h()->display();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my English and thank you in advance!

Edit:
I found out what was wrong:
in add function:

```
new_list->set_next(nullptr);
new_list->set_me(created);
new_list->set_first(this->get_first());
temp->set_next(new_list);
```

I forgot about:

```
new_list->set_me(created);
```

- the mistake in add function as one of you wrote.

Comment: try to boil it down to a minimal example, that may help you find & solve the problem by yourself. Also, what's the error?

Comment: You never initialize `T* me;` -> `if ((this->get_me()) == nullptr)` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Error is "this is nullptr". It appears when I try to add more than one Human to my Base

Comment: provide the full compiler details and the full error message. Is it a compile-time or run-time error???

Comment: ohhh... I thought that if I have List <T> class (not T class) i can make property T* something

Comment: It's unclear what the meaning/purpose of your `class List<>` is. Is it a linked list? but then why does it hold a `first` and a `next` field? Is it a node of a linked list? but then why does it hold a `first` field?

Comment: No, it's not run-time error. Full error message is: "Exception thrown: write access violation.
this was nullptr."

Comment: I don't believe you. If it's a compiler error, then the compiler will have reported a file and line number ...

Comment: "exception thrown" sounds like a run-time error, though.

Comment: "_No, it's not run-time error. Full compiler message is: "Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr."_" And yet, write access violations are run-time thing.

Comment: I was trying to make linked list with pointer to first element in list, and the first element has pointer to itself as a pointer to first

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to mislead...

Comment: A linked list typically contains a pointer to a first `node`, which is a `struct`/`class` of its own.

Comment: Is this code part of a learning exercise?  Homework?  It does not seem to be idiomatic modern C++.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the `this->` syntax by choosing different names between the parameters and the methods.

Comment: It's like learning exercise... I know I'm not good in programming yet but I want to be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop

> ```
> while (temp != nullptr)
> {
>     temp = temp->get_next();
> }
> ```

runs till temp is `nullptr` and then you do

> ```
> temp->set_next(new_list);
> ```

So, as you see, inside `set_next()` the `this` pointer is `nullptr`.

Please learn how to use a debugger and look at the call stack.

Comment: No, it isn't. But its the construct that leads to the error message the OP has asked about.

Comment: Thank you. I still have another error but I am trying to get rid of this on myself

Comment: @im_a_cat Your whole design is flawed. Better use `<list>`